# Efficient way to find week ending date without a calendar table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the below SQL code in MS SSMS to find the week ending date. I often have to switch between Wednesday and Sunday as the week ending day. Side note, my data sets are often in the 100,000's.

Is there a more efficient way to do this than what I have below other than using a calendar table?

```
/* Declare Variables */
DECLARE @WeekendingDay VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @DayNumber INT;
DECLARE @InputDate VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @conInputDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @outWeekending DATETIME;
DECLARE @CovertToInt VARCHAR(10);

/* --------------------Inputs-------------------- */

/* uncomment the weekending day you want */
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Monday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Tuesday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Wednesday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Thursday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Friday'
--Set @WeekendingDay = 'Saturday'
SET @WeekendingDay = 'Sunday';

/* Date you want the weekending of */               
SET @InputDate = '29/12/2016';

/* --------------------Process-------------------- */
SET @DayNumber = CASE @WeekendingDay
                   WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
                   WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
                   WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
                   WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
                   WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
                   WHEN 'Friday' THEN 6
                   WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 7
                 END;


SET @conInputDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @InputDate, 103);
SET @outWeekending = DATEADD(dd,
                             CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @conInputDate) = @DayNumber
                                  THEN 0
                                  ELSE -1 * DATEPART(DW, @conInputDate) + 7
                                       + @DayNumber
                             END, @conInputDate);

/* --------------------Output-------------------- */
PRINT @outWeekending;
```

Comment: This question will draw a lot of opinions which leads to closure, but if you are calling this a lot then i would consider a calendar table of all dates from (some date) to (some future date, years from now) which has the week start and end based on any combination. It will only have to be computed once... then you can query it or join to it from now on and save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: do you want to calculate the 'week ending' date for each of the 100,000s of records?  Is the expression going to form part of a set based SQL query?

Comment: you can save yourself one case by setting the DayNumber direct instead of going to WeekendingDay but it will not save you any time

Comment: @Cato I would use this in a set of query's. This is just printing for demonstration.

Comment: @scsimon Thanks. I'm always torn between a date table and on the fly workings. I'm forever having to modify a date table as my company like to switch views between departments and change when the year starts for them. Start of year varies for us every year depending on how timesheet weeks land.

Comment: @GuidoG Good call, I genuinely had not thought of doing that. I was sharing my workings with colleagues and I always try to be crystal clear despite the fact they are probably more experienced than myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the Monday of the week. Depending on what day you want to use as the end you can adjust it as needed.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()-5

SELECT
    @date
    ,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0)    --Monday
    ,DATEADD(DD,1,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Tuesday
    ,DATEADD(DD,2,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Wednesday
    ,DATEADD(DD,3,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Thursday
    ,DATEADD(DD,4,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Friday
    ,DATEADD(DD,5,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Saturday
    ,DATEADD(DD,6,DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date),0))    --Sunday
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't ran this yet but if the day was a Monday, would it show next Monday or current Monday as the week ending?

Comment: This will give the Monday of the week of date. So if @date was Monday it would give that day.  If it was Tuesday, it would give the day before. Adjust it for Sunday and, if ran on Monday would give the next Sunday. If ran on Sunday it would give that day.